# sudoers - when command is run as a specific user

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

I wish to keep certain environment variables when a certain command is run as a certain user under `sudo`. `man sudoers` seems to suggest that `Defaults` can do this, if I've read the paragraph copied below correctly (see highlighted part), but the syntax spec beneath it doesn't seem to match that (unless it's the `Runas` portion?) and I have found no examples. Is it possible? My current, failing attempt is:

```
/etc/sudoers.d/certain:4:23: syntax error
Defaults:certain-user!/certain-command.sh env_keep += "ENV_VAR1 ENV_VAR2"
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've tried variations of this (adding spaces, changing the command etc) but to no avail.

The paragraph I mentioned:

> Defaults
> Certain configuration options may be changed from their default values at run-time via one or more Default_Entry lines.  These may affect all users on any host, all users on a specific host, a specific user, a specific command, or ***commands being run as a specific user***.  Note that per-command entries may not include command line arguments.  If you need to specify arguments, define a Cmnd_Alias and reference that instead.

```
Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |  
                 'Defaults' '@' Host_List |  
                 'Defaults' ':' User_List |  
                 'Defaults' '!' Cmnd_List |  
                 'Defaults' '>' Runas_List
```

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you interpret "commands being run as a specific user" to mean "a specific command being run as a specific user", but I think it means "for all commands that are run as a specific user".

Anyway, it's not possible to add restrictions for both run-as and command to `Defaults` - the grammar shown here doesn't allow that. If it were instead:

```
Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |  
                 Defaults_Type '@' Host_List |  
                 Defaults_Type ':' User_List |  
                 Defaults_Type '!' Cmnd_List |  
                 Defaults_Type '>' Runas_List
```

Then what you want might have been possible, but as stated, the grammar only allows exactly these:

```
Defaults
Defaults@...
Defaults:...
Defaults!...
Defaults>...
```

Comment: I think I'm wrong about the host-based workaround - it should affect all other rules on the same host, including this with `ALL` as the host specifier.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll give this a go tomorrow and see if it works or if you're right about the host thing. Either way, much appreciated, I can see how I've probably misinterpreted the man page there.